# sometimes server ip address could not be found in microsoft viewer

Tags: office-app

I am using https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src= to get viewed doc and docx extension documents. Sometimes I am getting the issue view.officeapps.live.com server ip address could not be found (completely inconsistent). Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!